# Parsing structure/hierarchy of html and recreating it in a different form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, casperjs

I am trying to crawl some webpages with javascript to gather information about content's hierarchy. I'm using [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) to do the crawling, that is working ok so far.

The information that I want to parse is structured like this:

```
<ul>
    <a></a>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a>
                Category
                <span>Description for Category</span>
            </a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>SubCategory</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But what I want to end up with is this.

```
<ul>
    <li>Category
        <ul>
            <li>SubCategory</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to use the above html in a different webpage, so basically I'll be writing it to a file from casperjs so that I can then copy paste it into another document. I'm crawling because it's a tedious thing to do manually (90 some pages and lots of data per page).

What's the best way to deconstruct/parse a hierarchy, and then recreate it? Stay within the DOM and restructure using JQuery? Pull it out into a tree structure and rebuild it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note that this is a particular solution and will only work for the specific layout of code that you provided:**

I created a parser in jQuery that receives HTML markup in a textarea and converts it into the format that you are using:

```
$(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        //Read in HTML
        $("#parser").html($("textarea").val());

        //Parse
        var categories = $("#parser > ul").find("li h3 a");
        $(categories).find("span").remove();

        //Output result
        var output = "&lt;ul&gt;\n";
        for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++)
        {
             //Get subcategories for this category
             var subCategories = $($(categories[i])).closest("h3").siblings("div").find("ul li a");

             //Add markup to output
             output += "\t&lt;li&gt;" + minimize($($(categories[i])).html()) + "\n\t\t&lt;ul&gt;\n";

             for(var j = 0; j < subCategories.length; j++)
             {
                 output += "\t\t\t&lt;li&gt;"+$($(subCategories[j])).html() + "&lt/li&gt;\n"
             }

            output += "\t\t&lt;/ul&gt;\n\t&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ul&gt;\n"
        }

        $("#result").html(output);
    });

});

//Removes all white-space characters from the string.
function minimize(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu38x/)

---

It was a lot of work and is very customized. As I said earlier, if you look at the different selectors that are used here, this code is *very* tailored to this specific code layout.

Example:

```
var categories = $("#parser > ul").find("li h3 a");
```

This looks for a ul element just below parser that contains `<a>s` inside of `<h3>s` inside of `<li>s` to find the categories and then later uses

```
$($(categories[i])).closest("h3").siblings("div").find("ul li a");
```

which looks for an `<h3>` above the category `<a>` that has a sibling `<div>` with children `<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>`

So if the format is not this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>
            <a>Category</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>Subcategory</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It will not work.

Comment: Can't you use `casper.getHTML()`, assuming you know which part of html  you're interested in? or am i missing the point here ?

Comment: @rusln Sure you can use that to get the html in the same way that I was able to do $("textarea").val(), however the point of the code is to parse the HTML and pull out the important parts. I do that by taking in the HTML and putting it in a hidden div where I can then use jQuery to select the proper parts of the HTML and convert them into the DOM tree that the OP is looking for.

Comment: I ended up using an intermediate step as described in my own answer, but used parts of your solution to get there. It still suffers from the caveats you mention (it's very specific) but I think it's probably very hard to write a robust scraper. If the source website changes their html structure at all, you lose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this approach:

1. Scrape the tags from the existing website and assemble them into an array nested javascript object.
2. Writing them out with JSON.stringify to a file
3. Loading them into a new page as Javascript objects, and build the ul/li structure with a recursive function that traversed the javascript object.

I found it too hard to get my head around modifying the DOM as with the other answer(s). It was easier to break it down into multiple steps, with a well structured javascript object in the middle.